# PHPUnit - hasOutput() not working

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I've just started using PHPUnit for some testing, and am having trouble detecting output.
$this->hasOutput() returns false, even though I am echoing data.  What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

```
class DatabaseTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testOutput() {
        SampleDB::echoOutput();
        $result = $this->hasOutput() ? "true" : 'false';
        echo $result;
    }
. . .
```

Implementation:

```
class SampleDB {
    public static function echoOutput(){
        echo "hello world!";
    }
```

Running tests:

```
phpunit DatabaseTest
PHPUnit 4.2.6 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.hello world!false.

Time: 55 ms, Memory: 1.75Mb

OK (2 tests, 0 assertions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the source for `hasOutput` from my version of PHPUnit (3.7.34 so yours may differ; if it does my conclusions below may be inapplicable to your specific scenario):

```
/**
 * @return boolean
 * @since  Method available since Release 3.6.0
 */
public function hasOutput()
{
    if (strlen($this->output) === 0) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ($this->outputExpectedString !== NULL ||
        $this->outputExpectedRegex  !== NULL ||
        $this->hasPerformedExpectationsOnOutput) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The `output` member variable on the test case is only populated after test execution (including `tearDown`) is complete so it will always be empty while your test is executing and thus `hasOutput` will always return false.

I am not sure what the intended use of `hasOutput` was because I can't find it in the PHPUnit documentation.  Based on some grepping it looks like it is used when strict mode is on to complain if a test is completed and has output which was not explicitly expected.

If you need to do something conditionally in your test based on whether there is any output from the test you should be able to use `getActualOutput()` (again that's the 3.7.x version of the function; possible it changed in 4) which will return the currently buffered output string.

You can also use assertions like `expectOutputString()`.

e.g.

```
    public function testOutput() {
            SampleDB::echoOutput();
            $result = ($this->getActualOutput() != '') ? "true" : 'false';
            $this->expectOutputString('hello world!');
            echo $result;
    }
```

In this case the assertion would fail because the actual output of the test is `'helloworld!true'`

Comment: Thanks!  

I was trying to use this function to see if my code was outputting any data (ie. making sure it was echoing some output)--but hasOutput is actually used to determine if a test outputted data...makes sense.